How to set previous firetime in quartz trigger during trigger creation time
This code creates a trigger but the previousFireTime of the trigger is set to -1 by default. I want to set it to the time of trigger creation or current time when the trigger is created.
    @Override
    protected Trigger createTrigger() {
        LOG.info("Creating trigger for Usage Tracking Controller");
        final String frequencyOfUsageTracking = ApplicationProperty.USAGE_REPORTING_REPORT_FREQUENCY.getStringValue();
        if (Optional.ofNullable(frequencyOfUsageTracking).isPresent() && frequencyOfUsageTracking.equals("Monthly")) {
            return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(getJobName(), getJobGroup())
                    .startNow()
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.monthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(1, 1, 0)) // Run monthly at 01:00 AM at first of every month
                    .build();
        } else {
            return  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(getJobName(), getJobGroup())
                    .startNow()
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(1, 0)) // Run every day at 01:00 AM
                    .build();
        }
    }


I want to set it to the time of trigger creation or current time when the trigger is created.
